# Oracle for amplitude addition

Tags: circuit-construction, linear-algebra, oracles, arithmetic

Assume one is given two oracle circuits providing access to matrices $A_{ij}$ and $B_{ij}$ as follows (see eq. (6.2) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309)):
\begin{equation}
O_A |0\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle=\left(A_{ij}|0\rangle+\sqrt{1-|A_{ij}|^2}|1\rangle\right)|i\rangle|j\rangle \, ,\\
O_B |0\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle=\left(B_{ij}|0\rangle+\sqrt{1-|B_{ij}|^2}|1\rangle\right)|i\rangle|j\rangle \, ,
\end{equation}
where indices $i$ and $j$ are encoded with qubits in a the binary form. The said representation will be referred to as block encoding.

I am wondering if one could construct a circuit $O_{A+B}$ implementing
\begin{equation}
O_{A+B} |0\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle=\Bigl((A_{ij}+B_{ij})|0\rangle+\ldots|1\rangle\Bigr)|i\rangle|j\rangle \, .
\end{equation}

I placed $\ldots$ instead of $\sqrt{1-|A_{ij}+B_{ij}|^2}$ just to indicate that using ancillas and measurements would be OK.

**UPDATE: A BRUTE-FORCE SOLUTION**

For completeness I add a straightforward implementation based on the conversion to query oracles.

1. Use the controlled rotation circuit (see Proposition 4.7 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08309))
   [image]
   to convert the block-encoded oracles to query-encoded oracles $\widetilde{O}_A$ and $\widetilde{O}_B$:
   $$
   \widetilde{O}_A |0\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle = |\widetilde{A}_{ij}\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle \, ,\\
   \widetilde{O}_B |0\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle = |\widetilde{B}_{ij}\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle \, .
   $$
2. The consecutive application of oracles renders then
   $$
   \widetilde{O}_A \widetilde{O}_B |0\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle = 
   \widetilde{O}_A |\widetilde{B}_{ij}\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle =
   |\widetilde{A}_{ij} + \widetilde{B}_{ij}\rangle|i\rangle|j\rangle \, .
   $$

Would be nice to avoid converting to query oracles.

Comment: Given that $A_{ij}+B_{ij}$ is not necessarily in the unit ball anymore, what other restrictions are you envisioning for $A$ and $B$? Should they be normalized? And since generally $A$ and $B$ would be known classically, why not add them classically and then query the result?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using *linear combination of unitaries* (LCU) technique. It is described in the paper you mentioned (section 7.3). More specifically, see example 7.12

Comment: Seems like an overkill. I added some edits to the question.